# CSS border only appear on hover?

Tags: html, css, border

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/brumbul/D4D7J/5/)

You can see the problem from the jsfiddle link: a border with a certain thickness is set, but it does not appear generally (it only appear on hoover)...

At the same time, the very same structure works with no issue when the border is not involved.([JSFIDDLE sample 2](http://jsfiddle.net/brumbul/cn9v7/))

Here is the code:
**CSS**

```css
.DarkText {
    margin: 0;
}
.DarkText ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.DarkText a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #545353;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
.DarkText h2 {
    text-shadow: -1px 1px 1px #3D3D3D;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #545353;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 21px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family:'Segoe UI light', 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
.DarkText p {
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #545353;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    text-align: justify;
}
.DarkText .TwoBoxesDark li {
    width: 30.5%;
    height: 145px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 2% 2%;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.DarkText .orangeborder
{
    border-color: #D6D6D6;
    border-left: 10px solid #ff6a00;
    background-color: #D6D6D6;
    background: #D6D6D6;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F2F2F2 0%, #D6D6D6 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #F2F2F2), color-stop(100%, #D6D6D6));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F2F2F2 0%, #D6D6D6 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F2F2F2 0%, #D6D6D6 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F2F2F2 0%, #D6D6D6 100%);
}
.DarkText .orangeborder:hover
{
    border-color: #D6D6D6;
    border-left: 10px solid #ff6a00;
    background-color: #D6D6D6;
    background: #D6D6D6;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #D6D6D6 0%, #F2F2F2 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #D6D6D6), color-stop(100%, #F2F2F2));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #D6D6D6 0%, #F2F2F2 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #D6D6D6 0%, #F2F2F2 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #D6D6D6 0%, #F2F2F2 100%);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="DarkText">
    <ul class="TwoBoxesDark">
        <li class="orangeborder">
            <h2>Sample Title</h2>
            <p>This is just a sample paragraph</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please more specifically state what exactly you are looking for? Your post is currently a statement and not a question.

Comment: If your issue is that the text moves over on hover, [how's this](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/D4D7J/9/)? otherwise if it is just that there is no orange border, [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/D4D7J/10/)

Comment: Actually, I thought it was a clear question- I want the border to be visible all the time and the only thing changing to be the background grey colors...

Comment: @BettyCarlton Check Egari's solution below. Just add `li` to `.orangeborder`. So that it becomes `li.orangeborder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only appearing on hover because it is overridden here:

```
.DarkText .TwoBoxesDark li {
            width: 30.5%;
            height: 145px;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 0 2% 2%;
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

Comment out the `border: 1px solid transparent;`

Comment: not a good suggestion to comment out the common styles? check egari's solution.

Comment: YOU ARE THE MASTER :) THANK YOU...
And please excuse me- I am slightly blonde....

Comment: Egari's solution is extremely correct and this was the way my initial code was. However for this very purpose, this is a better option for me. Plus, it works for all the browsers (just adding one filter for the gradient in IE)

Answer (score 3):

.DarkText .orangeborder

The border-left of ".DarkText .orangeborder" is being overwritten by the border of ".DarkText .TwoBoxesDark li".

Changing

`.DarkText .orangeborder`

to

`.DarkText li.orangeborder`

or

`.DarkText .TwoBoxesDark li.orangeborder`

Will work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion- I know it works, but my point when creating those is to have multiple elements (TwoBoxesDark / ThreeBoxesDark/FourBoxesDark etc) and multiple color options and when the user works with it he will be able to create various combinations...

Comment: Alright in that case make sure either no two CSS rules conflict or any of the properties in the combination of CSS rules don't conflict. In the case of your problem described above the 'strength' or 'specificity' of the rule '.DarkText .orangeborder' is less than the rule of '.DarkText .TwoBoxesDark li' (The second rule is more specific and it will use that for conflicting rules). :)

Comment: Thank you @Egari... I was just missing the problem as I adjusted previously made CSS and this is particularly where my mistake came from...

Answer (score 1):

In your first Fiddle you have:

```
    .DarkText .orangeborder:hover
    {
        border-color: #D6D6D6;
        border-left: 10px solid #ff6a00;
```

So it's adding a left-border on hover.